# Redirect output files of binary (.exe)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, binary, output

I'm new programming on python. I have a binary that when I run it creates several data files from cmd in a loop. I would like to redirect all this output files that comes from binary(.exe) to a specific directory.

```
for x in range(5,A+1):
   out="C:\\Principal_path"+str(x) #Path where I would like to save the output files
   dir = r"/Binary_path"           #Path where is the Binary (.exe) + dat
   cont=0
   for x in range(1,B+1):     
       cont+=1
       cmdline = "soft.exe RunFILE"+str(cont)+".dat < "+out
       print(cmdline)
       rc = call("start cmd /K " + cmdline, cwd=dir, shell=True)
```

I can't find the way to save these files, I hope you could help me!
Best regards!

Comment: Change directory before you run it.

Comment: maybe you should use `cwd` with `out` and add `dir` directly to `cmdline` and to `RunFILE`. Something like `call(f"start cmd /K /Binary_path/soft.exe /Binary_path/RunFILE{cont}.dat", cwd=out, shell=True)`